# Importance of declaring object using superclass and derivated class

Tags: c#, inheritance, superclass

I cannot understand the importance of declaring object using the Type Superclass and the Son Class.

Let's say in the Superclass called Person I've declared the following members

```
string Name
string Lastname 

Public Person(string name, string lastname)

Name = name
Lastname = lastname
```

Now in the main I can type

`Person p = new Person()` and get access to Name and Lastname field.

Now I create the Class Student, which is going to inerith the Name and Lastnane fields. Now I type that Student has a new fields, called

```
int Graduate
```

And in the constructor I put

```
Public Student(int graduate) : base (name, lastname) 

Graduate = graduate
```

In the main now I can type

```
Student s = new Student
```

And get access to the Graduate field.

But now, what's the difference between typing

```
Student S = new Student() and
Person p1 = new Student()
```

If I'm going to inherit the constructor of the Superclass, why in some cases should I declare the Superclass followed by the constructor of the derived Class?

Comment: There is no difference in terms of the object that's completed.

Comment: Your example won't actually work, since you don't have `name` and `lastname` values in the `Student()` constructor.  You'd typically do this to extend the base class, so student would take `name`, `lastname` *and* `graduate` parameters.  The fist 2 parameters would be passed to the base class constructor, and the 3rd would be used in the inherited class.

Comment: Often I see declaring object as the following SuperclassName nameVar = new DerivedClass() What means? Sorry for my lack of skill

Comment: That's what you do if you want to stick to the abstraction, rather than tying yourself to a specific implementation. If done well, it allows you to separate whole domains of code from each other, making each easier to reason about. There's a school of design that prefers the least specific interface you need to do your job.